# Why firebird and others do not appear in Register Server database workbench?

Tags: sql, firebird

I try to create new connection with Firebird in Database Workbench. But, where is Firebird's Register Connection? What should I do first?

[image]

should appear like this

[image]

Comment: Exactly which tool is this? Is it Database Workbench by Upscene? Is it possible that you only downloaded the lite version for MySQL or bought the basic version with only support for MySQL?

Comment: It has nothing to do with Firebird. The question should be addressed to your "workbench" whatever it is

Comment: @Arioch'The Asking the question here and tagging it with Firebird is perfectly fine, as it is a "tool primarily used for programming", and it is related to Firebird, because that is what the OP wants to connect.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel "that is what the OP wants to connect." this wildcard covers questions like "suggest me a tool to open FB database". He can tag the question whatever he likes, but searching for advices on configuring his specific IDE have more chances to be fruitful if he addresses them to the said IDE community. While of course he might find people using the same IDE and knowing how to help him in any other community, Firebird community too. It is just inefficient and indirect

Comment: @Arioch'The You might want to freshen up on how Stack Overflow works, because what he did (apart from the unfortunate choice of using the tag 'workbench') is perfectly fine. Database Workbench **can** connect to Firebird, but only if you have the version or module that supports Firebird. It is a perfectly valid question to ask here, and it is perfectly fine to tag it with Firebird.

Comment: Like I said, he can tag with any tag, calling to attention of different communities. It is about efficiency. About figuring out which community has ready expertise in the problem you face.

Comment: @Arioch'The im sorry , I dont know if I should need a Pro edition for MySQL Workbench.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Database Workbench comes in a number of flavours, but most versions only target a specific database system, and you need to buy additional modules to add support for other database systems.

You likely downloaded the free "Lite Edition" which only supports MySQL, or bought a Basic or Pro edition for MySQL. If you want to use Database Workbench with Firebird, you will need to buy the Basic or Pro version for Firebird, or - if you already own Basic or Pro for another database system - you'll need to buy an additional module for Firebird support.

The documentation indeed contains a screenshot of the "Register Server Wizard" with all database systems listed, but this is probably because the documentation covers all variants, and was created with all modules active.

Comment: Thanks for ur information , maybe i need another tools .